# Screensave .scr behaviour with Flash and XML playlist

Tags: xml, flash, screensaver, playlist

I have a screensaver issue and I wondered if anyone could offer some advise please.

I'm trying to create an .SCR screensaver file from a Flash file.

The Flash file reads in a XML playlist and displays a series of videos and images like a sideshow sequentially.

The problem is when the Flash swf to turned into a screensaver .scr file the playlist is not active, the playlist file is read once, the first asset plays but the SCR is dumb and can't't/won't call the next asset to display. (I have been using SlideShowPro or JWPlayer for the show)

Does anyone know how I could fix this?

Does a SCR file need to be used as a Screensaver for a PC. Or can another file format be used? Like a SWF directly?

Can a SCR file be forced to behave like a SWF does?

Is there a piece of (inexpensive or free) software or code that help with this? I've tried a few but the SCR does handle the dynamic playlist.

Any thoughts greatly received!!!!

Answer (score 1):

My best guess would be to use [Zinc Builder](http://www.multidmedia.com/software/zinc/) for this.

Though it is not free, you CAN download a trial an see if you can pull it off with this.

Another option might be to embed all of your assets in the screensaver, however I guess that would defeat the purpose of what you are trying to achieve.

**EDIT**

[This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375225/swf-into-screensaver-possible) talks about a tool called [InstantStorm](http://www.instantstorm.com/) that will help you manage a screensaver with additional external files.
Furthermore, it is freeware so it might he worth a shot.

Cheers