# SWF into Screensaver possible?

Tags: flash, screensaver

Is it possible to make a SWF into a screensaver for Windows 7? How about without the compiler tool?

Comment: Did you do any research into this at all before posting your question? It took me less than 10 seconds to find Instant Storm using Google.

Comment: Yes, I did the research. I'm asking for a way to making screensaver type of thing without 3rd party freeware.

Comment: Then you should have specified that. Now I'm wondering *why* you don't want to use a 3rd party translator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Please use [Instant Storm](http://www.instantstorm.com/)**

Best of luck!